# Sublinear function is positively homogeneous.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

We let $\mathbb{E}$ be a Euclidean space and assume $f:\mathbb{E} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies
$$f(\lambda x + \mu y) \leq \lambda f(x) + \mu f(y) $$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{E}, \lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{R}_+.$

I want to show that this is equivalent to the usual definition of sublinearity, i.e.
$$ f(x+y) \leq f(x)+f(y), \quad f(\lambda x) = \lambda f(x)$$

The first inequality follows easily, however I'm having trouble proving that the function is positively homogeneous. So far I've proved $f(0)=0$ and thus $f(\lambda x) \leq \lambda f(x)$. How do i obtain the reverse inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the following:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f(x)&=f\big{(}\frac{1}{\lambda}(\lambda x)+0\big{)}\\
&\leq \frac{1}{\lambda}f(\lambda x)+f(0)\\
&=\frac{1}{\lambda}f(\lambda x)\\
&\Rightarrow \lambda f(x)\leq f(\lambda x)
\end{split}
\end{equation}